# PHP header pass parameters in url

Tags: php, header, http-headers

I have an index.php for registration, a login.php as the registration handler. when the registration is failed, it sent out the error message to client. I use this code for sending out the message

```
header('Location: http://localhost/musicshare/index.php?reg=false');
```

and receive in index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
        echo 'set';//for checking whether reg is set
        if($_POST['reg']=='false'){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Reg faile")';
            echo '</script>';
        }
    }
```

However, It seems not working at all; Please help, thanks.

Comment: If your question is answered accept your suitable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`:

```
if (isset($_GET['reg']) && $_GET['reg'] == 'false'){
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a header() it fires a `GET` request.

So you should use $_GET['reg']

```
if(isset($_GET['reg'])){
    echo 'set';//for checking whether reg is set
    if($_GET['reg']=='false'){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Reg faile")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```